# vue javascript filter object typeError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

I want to filter an object by states-name (e.g. Berlin, Bayern ...). This is my response from the API.

```
  "states":{

      "Bayern":{
         "total":13124737,
         "rs":"09",
         "vaccinated":254916,
         "vaccinated_by_accine":{
            "biontech":246384,
            "moderna":8532
         },
         "difference_to_the_previous_day":4878,
         "vaccinations_per_1000_inhabitants":19.42,
         "quote":1.94,
         "2nd_vaccination":{
            "vaccinated":67418,
            "difference_to_the_previous_day":8102
         }
      },
      "Berlin":{
         "total":3669491,
         "rs":"11",
         "vaccinated":74605,
         "vaccinated_by_accine":{
            "biontech":73012,
            "moderna":1593
         },
         "difference_to_the_previous_day":3306,
         "vaccinations_per_1000_inhabitants":20.33,
         "quote":2.03,
         "2nd_vaccination":{
            "vaccinated":18158,
            "difference_to_the_previous_day":953
         }
      },
```

This is my function in computed section:  (searchstring is an input-field in my markup)

```
computed: {    
filteredList() {   
        let filter = {};
        let searchString = this.searchstring.toLowerCase();
    
        Object.keys(this.vacciResults).forEach(key => {
          filter[key] = this.vacciResults[key].filter(function(item){
            return item.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);
          });
        });
    
        return filter
    
      },
    ...
    this.vacciResults = res.states;
```

I get this error, why? item should contain the states name.

[image]

new function:

```
   filteredList() {   
        
        let searchString = this.searchstring.toLowerCase();
    
        return Object.keys(this.vacciResults).reduce((carry, key) => {
            carry[key] = Object.keys(this.vacciResults[key]).filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchString))
          
            return carry

          }, {})
    
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `this.vacciResults[key]` is yet another object so you'll need to leverage `Object.keys()` on it as well. I've just used `reduce` here for clarity.

```
let searchString = this.searchstring.toLowerCase();

return Object.keys(this.vacciResults).reduce((carry, key) => {
  carry[key] = Object.keys(this.vacciResults[key]).filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(searchString))

  return carry
}, {})
```

Comment: OK, THX. I understand. But please, if possible,  give me the right syntax for the whole function.

Comment: @RalfBordé Okay. Added the searchString declarative.

Comment: I added the new function in the question, but it doesn't work. something is wrong with the brackets, i suppose.